# Legality of transferring IPA files between people

Tags: iphone, ipad, file

We are currently developing an app for a client in the US, we are based in the UK. We need to "proof" the app as we make changes with our client i.e. get them to check the updates before we go any further.

The issue we're having is that transferring an IPA file to our client has been advised by their legal team as illegal. Is there any other way (simply) to allow our client to view this app regularly as we update it?

Cheers

Comment: A clarification of what exactly they deem as "illegal" would probably help improve the useability of the answers.

Comment: This is not a programming questions, but a question for both your legal teams as regarding why sending an IPA might be illegal, as these reasons might also apply to any other means of viewing the app.

Comment: The reason I asked it here was because there's plenty of iPhone app developers here so therefore the ideal environment for it

Comment: I'd say that software questions are off-topic if it's a matter of overriding actual legal advice from lawyers.  Perhaps if the Software Law Stack Exchange site ever goes live, but it's not suited for any site (including Programmers.se) now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IANAL, however, their legal team is wrong. When I click Build and Archive, and then Share by Email, the generated email file contains an ipa. This is an Apple-sanctioned method of doing ad-hoc sharing of iPhone apps.

What is probably confusing them is that if you're pirating apps, you use ipa files as well. However, saying that sharing ipa files is illegal is like saying sharing .exe files is illegal. Sometimes, yes. In this case: no, so long as the devices that are running it have been properly provisioned.

Comment: How would one provision the device properly then?

Comment: Get the UDID for the device that will be used by the client, add it to an ad-hoc provisioning profile and build your app using that profile. This may help: http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20 ... also, **Build and Archive** in Xcode will easily allow you to distribute with your ad-hoc profile.